# How to create multithreading in a stateless session bean?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I have created Webservice using JAXWS and hosted it as stateless session bean in jboss6. 
Following is the web service code:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "CommonSmsServices", name = "CommonSmsServices", wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/CommonSmsServices.wsdl", endpointInterface = "com.sms.webservice.common.CommonServices")
public class CommonServicesImpl implements CommonServicesLocal,CommonServicesRemote {
      //.....
      // methods
      //.....

}
```

This works fine with a single Http session. Now I am facing the problem while running multiple sessions, that the response time becomes very slow.
I did YourKit porfiling for memory and threading sampling. Memory utilization look good. but in thread section it shows one htpp thread is waiting for other to complete.

I have also gone through the Java EE session bean documentation. It says session bean are single threaded. Is there a performance issue with session beans that handle multiple Http session concurrently?

Is there a way or configuration in JBoss AS 6 to improve my web service performance?

Comment: "session" in "stateless session bean" has nothing to do with user sessions that you seem to refer to in "multiple sessions". On the other hand, SSBs support multithreading with no effort on your part.

Comment: i have update my app issue. plz look into it.

Answer (score 1):

In an EJB (including Stateless ones) multithreading is supported by the container. If you want your data to be stored between to distinct calls you probably should use a Statefull bean instead; this also supports multithreading.